# How do I install Poweriso?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install **Poweriso** on my Ubuntu 17.04 installation.

I've already tried  `sudo mv -v /home/user/Desktop/poweriso /usr/bin/poweriso`, but I think it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean with *did not install*? Can you use it from terminal? Works for me

Comment: `sudo mv -v /home/user/Desktop/poweriso /usr/bin/poweriso` is not installing but moving a file. Did you make sure "poweriso" is executable?

Comment: The poweriso for Linux file comes from a .tar.gz archive. When it is extracted it is already executable and ready to run it from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Power ISO from https://www.poweriso.com/download-poweriso-for-linux.htm
2. Extract the .tar.gz file
3. Go to the extracted folder
4. Open the terminal and change the directory to the installed folder destination
5. type ./poweriso.sh